# confluent cloud starter spring-boot code is broken with Incompatible types: found: CompletableFuture, required: ListenableFuture

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

The source code supplied by confluence cloud, the people who created kafka, doesnt seem to work, and I dont know how to fix. The error is:

Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>', required: 'org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture<org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>'

The code they supply is as follows:

Producer.java

```
package com.ohds.kafka1;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureCallback;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.SendResult;

@Service
public class Producer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
    private static final String TOPIC = "bets";

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessage(String key, String value) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, key, value);
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
                logger.info(String.format("\n\n Produced event to topic %s: key = %-10s value = %s \n\n", TOPIC, key, value));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried changing "ListenableFuture" to "CompletableFuture" to match the kafkaTemplate call:

```
    CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, key, value);
```

but this then fails on the next line.

Any suggestions on how to fix appreciated.

Here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ohds</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka1</name>
    <description>kafka test project 1</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation could simply be out of date, and show Spring 2.x code, while you are using 3.2.2

[`KafkaTemplate#send`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html) returns a CompletableFuture, not `ListenableFuture`

This line is incorrect.

```java
ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, key, value);
```

Refer [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html) and [Spring Docs specific to the client version you are using](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/sending-messages.html), rather than from external sources.

As written there,

> In version 3.0, the **methods that previously returned ListenableFuture have been changed to return CompletableFuture**

Comment: thanks for the reply.  The documentation I am using is from today (23/2/24). When you crate a kafka cluster, it gives you the source code for spring boot to use it.  When I try to compile the given code, I get this error. PResumably something has changed since confluence cloud produced the code., but Im not sure how to fix.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "from today". It could have been written months ago with an older version. The Gradle in their documentation uses Spring 2.7.5. You are using 3.2.2. You'd "fix" it by downgrading, or rewriting the code. It is just a template, not meant to be used immediately without changes. https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/spring-boot/#create-project

Comment: That explains the issue.  it would be good to use 3.2.2.  Im trying to find a fix.